# Calculate magnitude of the gradient using higher order statistics

Tags: image-processing, statistics, gradient, blur

I am making a model for detecting blurred part of an image. I'm using features described in the paper [*Blurred Image Region Detection And Segmentation*](https://ieeexplore.ieee.org/document/7025898) by Hyukzae Lee and Changick Kim, and I have a problem with their equation for computing magnitude of the gradient.

In the paper they talk about

> using HOS enhance strong edges while suppressing weak edges and noise
> components

This is equation for calculating MG:

$$ MG(i) = log \left[ \frac{1}{N_{p_{i}}} \sum_{j \in P_i }\biggl\{\sqrt{\frac{I_x^2(j)+I_y^2(j)}{2}}\biggr\}^t\right]$$

> where $I_x$ and $I_y$ stand for the gradient of intensity value in
> horizontal and vertical directions, respectively. $P_i$ represents the
> patch centered at the ith pixel position and $N_{P_i}$ denotes the
> number of pixels in $P_i$.
>
> For the value $k$, we select it as 4 in terms of trade-off between
> performance and complexity of MG feature.

My main question is:

How do I calculate the $\{\}^t$ part? I was thinking this was just normal power but it isn't. I believe it's some statistical moment but how can I calculate it? It follows form notation that we calculate $\{\}^t$ from every number in the sum and then add them up. Or maybe I have to first add them up, and then calculate $\{\}^t$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, on the copy I see of the paper I can read:

[image]

Namely there is a match between $ k $ in the text and the power in the equation.

If you read about [Higher Order Statistics (HOS)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Higher-order_statistics) then you see the idea is to use high power of the sample.

If you treat the magnitude of the pixel as it is defined as a sample, then what they do is just raising it by $ k $.
They also specify that they chose $ k = 4 $.